# Android Spanned object

Tags: android, textview

Suppose I have an EditText:

```
Editable e = editText.getEditableText(); // length == 2
// ...attach a span  start=0, end=2 to e...

int index = e.nextSpanTransition(0, 2, Object.class);
```

According to this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html
`index` should be 0, since it says

> Return the first offset greater than or equal to start where a markup object of class type begins or ends

But `index` is 2. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Or am I even misinterpreting the docs, since it could mean "greater than `start` where a markup object begins, OR, equal to `start` where a markup object ends"?

Comment: your comment says: attach so maybe you mean setSpan?

Comment: Also this metod has a different comment in the source code: Return the next offset after <code>start</code> but less than or equal to <code>limit</code> where a span of the specified type begins or ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation also says:

> or `limit` if there are no starts or ends greater than or equal to `start` but less than `limit`

Where `limit` is the second parameter (2 in your case). Your span does not satisfy `less than limit` because it is equal to it. So it returns `limit`.

Here is the source code that explains it:

```
/**
 * Return the next offset after <code>start</code> but less than or
 * equal to <code>limit</code> where a span of the specified type
 * begins or ends.
 */
public int nextSpanTransition(int start, int limit, Class kind) {
    int count = mSpanCount;
    Object[] spans = mSpans;
    int[] starts = mSpanStarts;
    int[] ends = mSpanEnds;
    int gapstart = mGapStart;
    int gaplen = mGapLength;

    if (kind == null) {
        kind = Object.class;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int st = starts[i];
        int en = ends[i];

        if (st > gapstart)
            st -= gaplen;
        if (en > gapstart)
            en -= gaplen;

        if (st > start && st < limit && kind.isInstance(spans[i]))
            limit = st;
        if (en > start && en < limit && kind.isInstance(spans[i]))
            limit = en;
    }

    return limit;
}
```

Look at the last 2 `if`-sentences, in your case st=0, start=0, en=2, limit=2. The first `if` is false, the second `if` is false too. At the end it returns the unchanged `limit` parameter.